# Ansible - how to empty a folder

Tags: ansible

I need to delete files from a directory, but I'd like to keep the folder by ansible.

I've tried with file module, it turns out the directory is removed as well. 
Any suggestion?

```
    - name: empty dest directory 
      file:
        state: absent
        path: /path/to/directory/
```

Expected: directory: /path/to/directory is empty, but the directory exists

Actual: directory is also removed

Answer (score 2):

Why not just empty it first, then create it again?

```
- name: empty dest directory 
  file:
    state: absent
    path: /path/to/directory/

- name: recreate directory 
  file:
    state: directory
    path: /path/to/directory/
```

Comment: This won't preserve ownership and permissions.

Comment: Good point, set the ownership and permissions you want

Comment: Your answer is simple enough though. I tried to do nested loops etc. to get the file list in the directories. It's just not worth the complexity. It would be so easy if Ansible just had "state: empty"... Unfortunately, it doesn't.